# Thoughts on why this CASE Statement may not return results desired

Tags: sql

I am trying to use a CASE statement in Sisense that is only giving me back some of the results I need but not all. Hoping for some thoughts.

FA_CLS is Class
FA_DEXA and FA_MEXA are identifiers in the data for each class.
FA_STA and FA_DC are filters for certain records we are looking at.
The only data I am getting 'Pass' for is FA_CLS = VEHPRT, VEHSHO, and VEHRNT. Everything else is 'FAIL'. I know there are only 5 or 6 that should fail out of about 1700 rows. I tried trimming everything

```
SELECT CASE

    WHEN a.FA_CLS = trim('EQUIP')  AND a.FA_DEXA = trim('50020') AND a.FA_MEXA = trim('51000') THEN 'Pass'

    WHEN a.FA_CLS = trim('VEHADM')  AND a.FA_DEXA = trim('60220') AND a.FA_MEXA = trim('60330') THEN 'Pass'

    WHEN a.FA_CLS = trim('VEHSAL')  AND a.FA_DEXA = trim('60220') AND a.FA_MEXA = trim('60330') THEN 'Pass'

    WHEN a.FA_CLS = trim('VEHPRT')  AND a.FA_DEXA = trim('50040') AND a.FA_MEXA = trim('58000') THEN 'Pass'

    WHEN a.FA_CLS = trim('VEHSHO')  AND a.FA_DEXA = trim('50040') AND a.FA_MEXA = trim('58000') THEN 'Pass'

    WHEN a.FA_CLS = trim('VEHRNT')  AND a.FA_DEXA = trim('50040') AND a.FA_MEXA = trim('58000') THEN 'Pass'

    WHEN a.FA_CLS = trim('SHOP')  AND a.FA_DEXA = trim('50030') AND a.FA_MEXA = trim('51000') THEN 'Pass'

    WHEN a.FA_CLS = trim('FURN')  AND a.FA_DEXA = trim('60210') AND a.FA_MEXA = trim('61200') THEN 'Pass'

    WHEN a.FA_CLS = trim('LEASE')  AND a.FA_DEXA = trim('60200') AND a.FA_MEXA = trim('61200') THEN 'Pass'

    WHEN a.FA_CLS = trim('GOOD') AND a.FA_DEXA = trim('61000') AND a.FA_MEXA = trim('61200') THEN 'Pass' 

    ELSE 'Fail' 

    END 

    FROM [QS36F.FASSET] a

    WHERE a.FA_STA = 'A'

    AND a.FA_DC != '90'
```

Comment: `trim('50020')` does not really make sense, it's the same as `'50020'`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and `[QS36F.FASSET]` is an invalid identifier in standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: Instead of trimming the constants that have no blanks to trim, you should trim the columns, if you think they may have leading or trailing blanks that are in the way (`WHEN TRIM(a.FA_CLS) = 'EQUIP'` etc.) .

Comment: You can simply test your conditions: `select * from [QS36F.FASSET] where fa_sta = 'A' and fa_dc != '90' and fa_cls = 'GOOD' and fa_dexa = '61000' and fa_mexa = '61200';` Do you get rows? If not, play with the conditions until you hit data.

Comment: Anyway, you seem to suffer from a bad database design, if you think there may be undesired blanks in the strings. There should be tables holding all valid CLS, DEXA, and MEXA, and foreign key constraints to make sure your table contains no invalid data. And then you may even add a table with all 'Pass'  conditions, so you don't need all those `CASE WHEN` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

instead of trim the costant  .. you should trim the columns

```
SELECT CASE

WHEN trim(a.FA_CLS) = 'EQUIP'  AND a.FA_DEXA = '50020' AND a.FA_MEXA = '51000' THEN 'Pass'
WHEN trim(a.FA_CLS) = 'VEHADM'  AND a.FA_DEXA = '60220' AND a.FA_MEXA = '60330' THEN 'Pass'
WHEN trim(a.FA_CLS) = 'VEHSAL'  AND a.FA_DEXA = '60220' AND a.FA_MEXA = '60330' THEN 'Pass'
WHEN trim(a.FA_CLS) = 'VEHPRT'  AND a.FA_DEXA = '50040' AND a.FA_MEXA = '58000' THEN 'Pass'
WHEN trim(a.FA_CLS) = 'VEHSHO'  AND a.FA_DEXA = '50040' AND a.FA_MEXA = '58000' THEN 'Pass'
WHEN trim(a.FA_CLS) = 'VEHRNT'  AND a.FA_DEXA = '50040' AND a.FA_MEXA = '58000' THEN 'Pass'
WHEN trim(a.FA_CLS) = 'SHOP'  AND a.FA_DEXA = '50030' AND a.FA_MEXA = '51000' THEN 'Pass'
WHEN trim(a.FA_CLS) = 'FURN'  AND a.FA_DEXA = '60210' AND a.FA_MEXA = '61200' THEN 'Pass'
WHEN trim(a.FA_CLS) = 'LEASE'  AND a.FA_DEXA = '60200' AND a.FA_MEXA = '61200' THEN 'Pass'
WHEN trim(a.FA_CLS) = 'GOOD' AND a.FA_DEXA = '61000' AND a.FA_MEXA = '61200' THEN 'Pass' 
ELSE 'Fail' 
END 
FROM [QS36F.FASSET] a
WHERE a.FA_STA = 'A'
AND a.FA_DC != '90'
```